# Generated keys for ID-column gives back null in table record

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am new to Java and above all to JDBC. I am trying to develop a simple DAO implementation for a GUI, in which fields from a panel get filled out and the data gets stored in an Oracle DB table named EventList. At the moment, it works with all the field of the class Event (Model) with the exception of the EventID column.

I am trying to generate an auto-increment integer through the statement GENERATED KEYS, but, even though I tried different ways to reorganize the "INSERT" query in the method saveData2(), the record remains null and no keys are generated. What I am doing wrong? Every hint would be really appreciated!

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EventDAOImpl implements EventDAO {

    @Override
    public void saveData2(Event event) {
        OracleDsSingleton ora =   OracleDsSingleton.getInstance();
        int primKey = 0;
        try {
            Connection connection = ora.getConnection();
            String addQuery = "INSERT INTO EventList(EventName, EventPlace, EventDate, EventDescription, EventCategory) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            //PreparedStatement ptmt = connection.prepareStatement(addQuery, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); 
//          ResultSet generatedKey = ptmt.getGeneratedKeys();
//                      if (generatedKey.next()) {
//              int key = generatedKey.getInt(1);
//              System.out.println(key);
//            }
            String columnNames [] = new String [] {"EventId"};
            
            PreparedStatement ptmt = connection.prepareStatement(addQuery, columnNames);
            
            ptmt.setString(1, event.getName());
            ptmt.setString(2, event.getPlace());
            ptmt.setString(3, event.getDate());
            ptmt.setString(4, event.getDescription());
            ptmt.setString(5, event.getCategory());
            
            //ptmt.executeUpdate();
                        
            if(ptmt.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                java.sql.ResultSet generatedKey = ptmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                if (generatedKey.next() ) {
                    event.setEventID(generatedKey.getInt(1));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Data successfully added!");
            //System.out.println("Table updated with EventID = " + primKey);
            System.out.println(event.getName());
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image: The GUI-Panel]

[image: The EventList Table-Schema]

[image: The stored datas]

Comment: Please remove all code not required to demonstrate the problem, especially the UI related code, which is irrelevant. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please show us the create table statement for `EventList`, specifically how `EventId` was defined (if DB does not autogenerate the field on insert - there is nothing to return you back)

Comment: The table EventList was created with a SQL-query directly in database. EventID was simply defined as Integer.

Comment: Which Oracle version and which Oracle JDBC driver version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Most things in the JDBC standard are optional. DBs are free to return nothing for `.getGeneratedKeys()`. Even when you ask for them. But you didn't, so, there's hope!

Try `con.prepareStatement("SQL HERE", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)` first. But, if that doesn't work, you're in for a lot more effort. Run a query to fetch the next value from the sequence (and figuring out the name of that sequence in order to do this can be quite a job!), then insert that explicitly. Let's hope it doesn't need to come to this.

NB: Modern DB design generally ditches the concept of an auto-count ID because keeping that counter 'in sync' with replicated servers and all that jazz is a giant headache. If you're still at the beginning phases of all this, why not follow modern conventions? Make the ID a UUID, and just let java generate it. They are no longer consecutive values, instead, they are long randomly generated strings (and with enough bits that even trillions if inserts still have less chance of a collision than you winning the lottery without buying a ticket whilst getting struck by 2 separate meteors, and lightning, all at once).